# WKWebView's init with frame and config is offset down, iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a UIView called webViewContainer, with proper constraints, and this view has background color red for testing purposes. I need to init WKWebView with frame and configuration. When I do this, the view appears to be offset down (both top and bottom edges are shifted down it seems).

Approach 1:

```
webView = WKWebView(frame: webViewContainer.frame, configuration: config)
    if let webView = webView {
        webViewContainer.addSubview(webView)
    }
```

Approach 2:

```
webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
    webView?.frame = webViewContainer.frame
    if let webView = webView {
        webViewContainer = webView
    }
```

None of the above and conbinations of those seem to work. What am I missing?
[image]

Comment: webViewContainer?  I have no idea where it comes from.

Comment: sorry, that's the red UIView I mention

Comment: set webViewContainer.bounds instead of the frame.

Comment: `webViewContainer = webView`. not really getting this part!?

Comment: @RajaKishan saves the day! Please post this as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you seem to work with constraints anyway you might wanna add them to your webView as well:

```
webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
if let webView = webView {
   webViewContainer.addSubview(webView)
   webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webViewContainer.leadingAnchor),
      webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webViewContainer.trailingAnchor),
      webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webViewContainer.topAnchor),
      webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webViewContainer.bottomAnchor)
   ])
}
```

Comment: actually, you were correct. Bounds is not working correctly, now after 2 weeks I came to a point where it displayed content incorrectly. So I accepted this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here you are setting webViewContainer's frame so the frames have different x and y positions that's why the inner subview set downside.

You should need to use bounds. Bounds return x and y zero so you will get perfect results.

Replace your code with this

```
webView = WKWebView(frame: webViewContainer.bounds, configuration: config)
```

Comment: this might break the webViews content size and the website will not adjust it's size accordingly. try loading `http://www.google.com` and see the result

Comment: @DanielMarx why it breaks? it's the same as yours ans just the difference is I used to frame and you used constraint both are the same and this solution is for the first approch.

Comment: would like to send you a screenshot, the content is not displayed properly with your approach. alternatively you could update the web views frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` on UIViewController level. And I need to object set using bounds/frame is the same as using constraints :)

Comment: @DanielMarx at this point you right. Need to update frame in ```viewDidLayoutSubviews()``` because initially, the frame is not getting correct in ```viewDidLoad```

Comment: and the mean thing is: if you use the same device on Storyboard and Target simulator you might not even notice it right away because in this case the bounds in viewDidLoad() will be the correct ones

Comment: @DanielMarx Yeah, I know this thing

Comment: just one last adjustment:  adding  webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight] should work as well.